# Assign and return bash variable from a running Docker container using exec

Tags: docker, docker-exec

I'm just trying to get the hang of how to work with an active Docker container I/O using the exec function.

I created a simple container with a bash session:

`docker run -it -d --name my_container ubuntu bash`

I gave the container a variable

`docker exec my_container bash -c my_var=5`

I ask for the variable back

`docker exec my_container bash -c 'echo "$my_var"'`

and it prints nothing.

How do I preserve a variable in memory between container runs? I eventually want to access much larger objects like arrays without saving them to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Each invocation of `docker exec` creates a new shell and environment variables aren't persisted across shells.

Try creating something that will persist, e.g. a file:

```sh
docker exec my_container bash -c "echo Hello > /freddie.txt"
```

Then:

```sh
docker exec my_container bash -c "more /freddie.txt"
::::::::::::::
/freddie.txt
::::::::::::::
Hello
```

Comment: Interesting. How do I store it in memory?